# Experience Running MS SQL 2008 on a Win 2008 in a KVM Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, kvm-virtualization

I am thinking of either running MSSQL 2008 on a bare metal machine or in a Ubuntu Guest based KVM virtual machine. The server itself is quite well provisioned.

I want to use KVM, but my primary concern is the disk I/O - directly vs through the KVM based VM.

Does anyone know:

1. If the I/O performance is
   comparable?
2. Are there any drivers
   that make win 2008 perform better on
   a KVM or are these already part of
   the KVM base virtualization?
3. Any tools/scripts/command I can run to
       compare my bare metal I/O thoughput
       to that via the VM.

Any other advise would be welcome...relatively new to this :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Performance is not 100% the speed of
   the disk subsystem, but pretty close
   if you avoid overhead. In general,
   it is recommended to use raw,
   preallocated images, and use qcow2
   only for snapshots.
2. Virtio drivers can make the VM go
   much faster. They are available from
   linux-kvm.org.
3. iozone comes to mind

I have seen ubuntu and gentoo act weird with kvm, which has been fixed by a reinstall of the right packages. Never seen the same on fedora or RHEL though - everything works out of the box there.

Comment: Thanks @dyasny you have helped me more that once. Can you kindly provide a link to a Ubuntu signed driver if there is one. I found this from the link:[link](http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/images/). There seems to be none for  Ubuntu. I am trying to avoid using src to build and sign it.

Will try out iozone and see how to use it. Again thanks!

Comment: you can use these drivers with Ubuntu IMO, those are just images that contain windows binaries.

Comment: I tried installing the drivers with - right click and install, That did not work. It says the Inf does not support this kind of install. Btw, do you know which folders to use from the ISO for network and storage?

I am using F:\viostor\Wlh\amd64 for win 2008 64 bit storage and F:\NetKVM\Vista\amd64 for the Network drivers.

Comment: how exactly did you "rightclick and install" ? the viostor driver should be picked while the windows VM is isntalled, otherwise, you shouldn't be able to see the virtio disk at all

Comment: @dyasny, I was sure that would not work. The VM is booting using the HD and the bus in the xml says IDE. I somehow need to change it to a virtio disk, not sure how exactly. Do I change the boot sequence to use the cdrom first, then install the drivers? Do I add the driver iso as a second cdrom?

Sorry I am new to this! Is there a step by step / readme on how to install this for a Win 2008 an existing VM?

Comment: if you already installed as IDE, you're stuck with it, unless you want to go hacking at windows internals. The right way to do it is to build a VM with a virtio disk, and also add a floppy emulation to the hardware list of the VM. Then you use the .vfd file at the fedorahosted site as the floppy image, and the Windows ISO as the boot image. When Windows loads, it will not see the HDD, so you select "load driver", and point it at the A: floppy drive. When the driver loads, you'll see the disk, and you can install Windows. The same floppy can later be used as the source for vioNet drivers

Comment: I have posted a full question for this at: [http://serverfault.com/questions/258852/how-to-install-virtio-drivers-for-win-2008-on-kvm](http://serverfault.com/questions/258852/how-to-install-virtio-drivers-for-win-2008-on-kvm)
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry did not see your comment, before posting the question. Is there a virt-install command that I can use. Maybe I will just reinstall the OS, there is not data on it yet.

Comment: there's another option, btw - slipstream the virtio drivers into the windows ISO