# How to install virtIO drivers for Win 2008 on KVM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, kvm-virtualization

This is a follow up to a pervious question. I have a Ubuntu host with a Win 2008 KVM. To improve performance the network and IO - @dyasny and the documentation recommends installing virtIO drivers. I did follow this : 
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers

Downloaded the ISO from:
http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/images/

Now I am not sure how to proceed. I have the Win 2008 VM already installed with the virtual disk in RAW format with an IDE bus.

I opened the iso and have several folders. Like
E:\Balloon
E:\NetKVM
E:\vioserial
E:\viostor

I am assuming NetKVM is for the network drivers and viostor is for the disk drivers.
For the NetKVM, there is only Vista and XP sub-folders.

Similarly for the viostor: there is a folder structure like below.
E:\viostor\Win7
E:\viostor\Wlh
E:\viostor\Wnet
E:\viostor\WXp

So in summary, my questions:

1. Which folders should we use for Win
   2008 64 bit?
2. How do I install the NetKVM for an
   existing VM?
3. How do I   ins tall the viostor for
   an existing VM?
4. Finally, just out of curiosity,
       what is Ballon and vioserial drivers
       for?

Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, as I already mentioned - you have 3 options:

1. hack windows to accept virtio
   drivers for the boot device (highly
   unrecommended) and then switch the
   disk interface to virtio
2. reinstall with virtio, using the
   drivers you mention this time on a
   floppy image or ISO attached to the
   VM
3. slipstream the virtio drivers into
   your windows ISO and reinstall

Comment: Hi Dyasny, I decided to just reinstall this from the get go. So I used virt-manager to create a new VM and then adjusted the storage to remove the IDE and added a virtIO drive. I use the floppy (vfd) based drivers, which help recognize the unallocated drive. However, after the drive shows up as allocated - Windows installation is unable to proceed. It says "Windows is unable to find a system volume that meets its criteria for installation.". I tried partitioning nothing worked. Any ideas. It is 64 bit btw?

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug: reported here [https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=568294](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=568294). Basically we need to make sure the hd is set to be bootable. Either we need to say boot=on at the command line or in my case I just changed the xml using virsh to include <boot dev='hd'/>
after the cdrom boot. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: glad you figured it out. Yes, qemu requires the disk is set to bootable, and the management should do that automatically for a new guest. It actually works for me on my F14 laptop

Comment: I am using F14, I think (the latest vfd is F14?) and virt-manager to setup the VM. Subjectively speaking, the IO performance with virtIO drivers is much better based on the responsiveness of the application (asp.net app). Now just have to test it for sustained periods of time to make sure everything is working as expect. So far so good.

Answer (score 4):

1. I would hazard a guess at the latest versions (Vista / Win7), windows won't happily install drivers that it can't support.
2. Add a virtio nic, start the VM, install drivers when Windows looks for them, remove non-virtio nic.
3. Add a temporary virtio disk, install drivers, remove temp disk and change your boot disk to virtio.
4. The Balloon driver is for [Memory Ballooning](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#Is_dynamic_memory_management_for_guests_supported.3F), but I have never managed to install it on any of my VM's, vioserial is apparently so you can have [more than one serial port](http://blog.allanglesit.com/2011/03/kvm-guests-install-virtio-drivers-for-windows-guests/).